# Grails plugin version compatibility

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy

Anyone know if I write a Grails plugin using Grails 2.2.1 (which uses Groovy 2.0) and use some Groovy 2.0 features e.g. @TypeChecked and if a Grails project that is using an earlier version of Grails and an earlier version Groovy use this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the plugins and groovy versions of course are not backward-compatible in terms of new features. you shall prepare a backward-compatible version of your plugin by removing groovy 2.x features out of it

Comment: Any tips on how I could support both at the sametime?

Comment: just don't use new groovy features, like annotations, multiple assignment or leaving out brackets.